# How to make Material UI modal and dialog scrollable?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a mui modal where a lot content is to be displayed. When I open the modal, the top content gets cut-off and I am unable to scroll up.
I have already tried adding {overflow:"scroll"} property to the modal. However, it is't working. This is the code I am currently using:

```
  <Modal
    open={viewCreateSegmentModal}
    onClose={() => handleCreateSegmentModal(false)}
    sx={{ 
    overflow:'scroll',
    height:'100%'}}
  >
    <div style={{overflow:"scroll"}}>
      <CreateSegmentModal
        modalControl={(value) => handleCreateSegmentModal(value)}
      />
      </div>
  </Modal>
```

[image: This is how the modal is getting displayed.]

[image: This is the top content getting cut-off. If I increase the number of rows under all conditions, the start getting cut-off too.]

Any suggestions to how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Can you provide more code so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: There isn't really any code which I can provide. The content being rendered by <CreateSegmentModal> is getting cutoff no matter if its simple text or other ui components. The modal doesn't even show some of the top content. It just starts off from somewhere in-between and then only scrolls downwards.

Comment: I still think you should provide more code, I can't see the issue with what you have there. I suspect it will be a child element with a set height or something

Comment: Check this out https://www.webknowledge99.com/2022/08/how-to-scroll-modal-in-material-uimui.html I tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting your Modal content in a Box rather than a div, and putting the overflow: scroll on that - something like the below:

```
  <Modal
    open={viewCreateSegmentModal}
    onClose={() => handleCreateSegmentModal(false)}
  >
        <Box className="modalBox" sx={{position: "absolute", overflowY: "scroll", maxHeight: "90%"}}>

         <CreateSegmentModal
           modalControl={(value) => handleCreateSegmentModal(value)}
         />
      </Box>
  </Modal>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I combined both this and emTeeDub's answers it worked very well

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue with Material UI's Modal component as well. To add to other's comments I did this below and it does the trick. Note: I also have a styles-in-js set up to display the modal in the center of the window. Using MUI 5.8.x w/ React. As Below:

```js
...
import { Modal, Box, ... } from '@mui/material';
...


...
const formStyle = {
    // These 4 below are positionings I used for larger 
    // height viewports - centered
    position: 'absolute', 
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    // other styles...
    width: '52%',
    maxWidth: '600px',
    minWidth: '270px',
    boxShadow: 24,
    py: 4,
    borderRadius: 3,
    zIndex: 100,
    // media query @ the max height you want (my case is the 
    // height of the viewport before the cutoff phenomenon) - 
    // set the top to '0' and translate the previous 'y' 
    // positioning coordinate so the top of the modal is @ the 
    // top of the viewport
    '@media(max-height: 890px)': {
        top: '0',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, 0%)'
    }
};


const MyStubbornModal = () => {
  ...
  return (
    ...
      // set the modal overflowY to scroll
      <Modal sx={{overflowY: 'scroll'}} disableScrollLock={false} ... >
        // I have an inner div (MUI Box), designated as a 'form' 
        // that is assigned the style above
        <Box sx={formStyle} component="form" ... >
          ...
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    ...
  );
}

export default MyStubbornModal;
```

Comment: While this works, note that it scrolls the whole modal and not just what is inside.